# What is he saying in this video ( time frame 18-22 sec)?

Tags: meaning, listening

I am watching Liam Gallagher and I am trying to translate all he's sayinng but I am not too sure what is he saying in the 18-22second 
I think he is saying " Should I tell you what get on my thinkings?" I searched the phrase but could not find any relevant result for the meaning so I guess I am not catching the right word? 
video url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIgNHUMzKbA&t=124s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the other fellow interrupts him in the middle of his thought. He starts out, as you also hear, "Shall I tell you what gets on my ..."

We imagine he is about to say "nerves" (or maybe some more creative expression with that meaning), but the other guy butts in with, "go fer it".

So it sounds to me like the first speaker then loses his train of thought in the middle of his sentence and switches over to a different expression (maybe something like "My thing is....") finishing up with, " ... thing is."

That's the way I hear it, but I'd be surprised if you could get a lot of people who were 100% certain about each word in this clip. The speech is fast and casual and they are having a lot of fun, laughing and interrupting. The mood and meaning certainly come through loud and clear though.

Comment: I was thinking it was go for it :) thanks it helps me

Comment: I'd have thought practically *all* Mancunians (inhabitants of Manchester, where Liam Gallagher comes from) would catch every word he says. I'm not, but as a Brit I've heard the accent an awful lot - and although I didn't listen to the whole clip (*and* I'm using the crappy speakers built into my monitor), I didn't notice anything I couldn't catch. It might be "tricky" for foreigners (esp Americans), but it's quite normal to have to cover a wide range of accents in the UK (apparently we have far more accents than they do in America).

Comment: @THEGreatGatsby, I'm sure FumbleFingers, below, is correct. I never heard before of "gets on my tits", but it sounds exactly-right, now.

Answer (score 6):

What Liam Gallagher is *about* to say is *Shall I tell you what **gets** on my **tits**?*

> ***get on someone’s tits*** - *to annoy someone a lot* <sub>([macmillandictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get-on-someone-s-tits))</sub>

...but because he knows he's on the radio, he balks at coming out with such a coarse turn of phrase, so what he *actually* says is *Shall I tell you what gets on my ...er... **thingies**?*

---

Note that this is very much a *British* expression - you wouldn't often hear it from an American, for example. It's also worth pointing out that women are just as likely to use it as men (after making allowances for the fact that *on average*, women don't swear as much as men anyway).

Comment: Thingies are very common in BrE conversation - so are thingummies and thingumajigs. Liam Gallagher is speaking a weird blend of Manchester and Estuary.

Comment: ***Thingy/thingies*** is just one (not particularly common) general-purpose term for something you either don't know the name of, or that you don't *want* to use the word you do know. If Gallagher were put in the same situation several times, it's quite possible he'd usually choose something else, such as ***doobries, whatsits, whatchamacallits***. I have the distinct feeling that at least *part* of his hesitation is because his first choice of euphemistic alternative was something that doesn't pluralise well, so he hesitated a bit longer than he would have done otherwise.

Comment: (That's to say, ***thingies*** sounds natural enough to me there, but ***thingummies*** or ***thingumajigs*** would sound more than a bit weird to me in this exact context - and probably to Gallagher himself too.)